# Components in Div is centered, cannot move left side or right side of the screen

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on gmail copy project. So i have to create a div which conatins component like inbox,send,draft etc. Whenever I create a component its centered and if i try to move, the icon disappear and the components are arranged irregularly.[Screenshot of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag2ej.jpg).

```
`.sidebarOption{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #818181;
}

.sidebarOption:hover,
.sidebarOption:hover > p,
.sidebarOption:hover > h3,
.sidebarOption--active,
.sidebarOption--active > p,
.sidebarOption--active >h3 {
    background-color: #fcecec;
    color: red;
    font-weight: 800 !important;
}

.sidebarOption.MuiSvgIcon-root{
    padding: 5px;
}

.sidebarOption > h3{
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.sidebarOption > p{
    display: none;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.sidebarOption:hover > p{
    display: inline;
}

.sidebarOption--active > p {
    display: inline;
}

`
```

after using relative postion this is how it looks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1SGF.jpg)

I have tried using postion and right css element to adjust but the icon disappear and the components are irregularly arranged.

Comment: Can you post a demo of this on codesandbox, jsfiddle or something?

Comment: I'm new here how can i do that

Comment: But I follow a youtube to build this
The link is [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7nrXjS6Dqs&t=4457s]
Time:1:10:30s
But in the video , by dault the components are in left

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I use position : relative and right :650px
when I use display : flex
everything came together as it supposed to.